# Is it safe to have an invalid operation in the second half of && in an if statement?

Tags: c++

Is this safe:

```
if(sprite->numberOfSides !=0 && sprite->value%sprite->numberOfSides!=0)
```

if sprite->numberOfSides can == 0?

The reason I ask, is if I frame the if statement like this:

```
if(sprite->value%sprite->numberOfSides!=0 && sprite->numberOfSides !=0)
```

I get an exception (because you can't n%0). Reversing it to the former statement works fine, but I don't want trouble down the road when compiling for different devices.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it's safe. **Short-circuiting** is guaranteed by the standard.

This means that if the first part of an and (`&&`) expression evaluates to `false`, it's guaranteed that the second part won't be evaluated.

From C++03 - **5.14/1**

> The `&&` operator groups left-to-right. [...] the second operand is not evaluated if the first operand is `false`.

Comment: It's guaranteed as long as its the standard `operator &&`. It is not for an user defined `operator &&`.

Comment: And of course `||` is safe as well even when the RHS is only safe to evaluate in the case of the LHS being false.

Answer (score 4):

It is safe as long as you are talking about the built-in `&&` operator. As other answers already noted, the evaluation of the built-in operator is short-circuited: the left operand is always evaluated first, and if it evaluates to `false`, the right operand is not even touched.

However, when you are dealing with overloaded operator `&&`, it behaves as any other overloaded binary operator, meaning that both operands are evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for built in types (like booleans). This behavior is known as short circuiting. This occurs because && is actually a function associated with the first statement in the expression, though it special syntax due its status as an operator as well. Inside this function, there will generally be a check for nullity as well as if the expression is false. In the case of the && operator, if the boolean is false, this is sufficient grounds to cease evaluation of the logical expression and will result in saved evaluation time.